# Open password-protected Access 2010 database in VB2010

Tags: vb.net, passwords, ms-access-2010

I need to open a password-protected Access 2010 database from a VB2010 application.  The connection works fine without a password, so I know I have all other parameters set correctly.  But when I add the password to the connection string I get an error, "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."  I know the password is correct because it works when I copy and paste it into the password dialog when opening the database directly in Access.

Here is the code I use.  The error occurs at the adapter.fill command:

```
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\MyData.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyPassword;")

    Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    command.Connection = conn
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"

    Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Dim adapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command)

    adapter.Fill(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in Access 2010 : https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2010/

Quote :

> With database password This is the connection string to use when you
>   have an Access 2007 - 2013 database protected with a password using
>   the "Set Database Password" function in Access.
>
> ```
> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
> Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
> ```
>
> Some reports of problems with password longer than 14 characters. Also that some characters
>   might cause trouble. If you are having problems, try change password
>   to a short one with normal characters.
>
> **Note! Reports say that a
>   database encrypted using Access 2010 - 2013 default encryption scheme
>   does not work with this connection string. In Access; try options and
>   choose 2007 encryption method instead. That should make it work. We do
>   not know of any other solution. Please get in touch if other solutions
>   is available!**

Also, as a tip, you don't need to say

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Connection String")
```

You can just do

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Connection String)
```

Answer (score 0):

From:https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22485495/edit

The method I used to do this is actually quite simple:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set dblink = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(strDbFile, False, False, ";PWD=" & strP)

For Each strTable In strLinkedTablesArray
     DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", dblink.name, acTable, _
         strTable, strTable
Next
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Worked on this problem for a while.  All the clues are mentioned above, but had to incorporate them all together...

Under File - Options - Client Settings (scroll to the bottom)...

Default Open Mode = Shared

Default record locking = No Locks

Encryption Method = Use legacy

Unencrypt and re-encrypt the database

```
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=c:\dt\GenericDetail.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password='ThePassword';"
    .Open
```

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/210e52e6-cae7-4312-a08a-20c3e50bc17d/ace-oledb120-excel-password-protected-access-trouble?forum=adodotnetdataproviders