# how can I use connection password to open Microsoft Access database using Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I put a password on access database and tried to access it by this code but when using (cnn.open) it doesn't work and do not access the database. How can I do it? 
(I put 1234 for password example)

```
cnn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="""";Data Source=C:\SecGrd" & _
            "\SecGrd.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System databas" & _
            "e="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine " & _
            "Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet" & _
            " OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:C" & _
            "reate System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Cop" & _
            "y Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLE" & _
            "DB:SFP=False")


    CCCommand.SelectCommand.Connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="""";Data Source=C:\SecGrd" & _
    "\SecGrd.mdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System databas" & _
    "e="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine " & _
    "Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet" & _
    " OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:C" & _
    "reate System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Cop" & _
    "y Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLE" & _
    "DB:SFP=False")
    CCCommand.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from CC_Main"

    CCCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", StudentsGradesDataset.CCMTable)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to an Access database that has a database password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049017/connecting-to-an-access-database-that-has-a-database-password)

Comment: Also see: [Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/).  -- [Open password-protected Access 2010 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214602/open-password-protected-access-2010-database-in-vb2010). Check SO on how to specify a connection string (once, possibly).

Comment: What is the error you getting? It seems that you omit opening of the connection. `CCCommand.SelectCommand.Connection.Open`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem 20 years ago!
So i found the solution and used this connection string Since 20 years ago!

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\data\base\main.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234"
      providerName="System.Data.OleDb"
```

Notes:

1- Put your database path here: |DataDirectory|\data\base\main.mdb

2-It's working sice 20 years ago so Enjoy it!!!

Comment: cnn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|C:\SecGrd|\data\base\SecGrd.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234; providerName = System.Data.OleDb")

Comment: this is correct: Source=C:\SecGrd\data\base\SecGrd.mdb you must remove '|' from your code